# TSP65070 and OMAP 1V8 pull up to 2.7V

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, dsp

I want to use the TPS65070, the power solution for DSP to power the OMAP L138, but i read in the errata sheet of the OMAP L138 [OMAP L138 Errata](http://www.ti.com/lit/er/sprz301m/sprz301m.pdf) page 25 that the 1V8 power supply can pull up to 2.7V when using Dual-Voltage at 3.3V.
[image: 3V3 current leakage]
One of the proposed solution in the errata document is to use additional shunt regulator (page 27) TLVH431. But the problem is the leakage current into the DVDD18 supply is 140mA and the regulator provide 70mA ? So, the use of two regulators can resolve the problem, or can anyone suggest any other regulator which provides 140 mA?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following discussion in TI E2E community provide the answer for this question:
http://e2e.ti.com/support/power_management/etc_power/f/216/p/439227/1576675#1576675